# Simulate piston for forklift using PhysX 3.4 ( Unity 2018.3 )

Tags: unity, physics, physx

I need to simulate a piston for a forklift, but I don't really know how to create an accurate physics model.

The forklift ( a car with some wheel colliders ) should react to the force applied by cargo on the forks, but the forks should also move along the lift axis and sideways while colliding with cargo and the environment, and the forklift should react to the changes, if the forks hit a wall, the forklift should react accordingly, and if the forks hit the floor or a ceiling, it should lift itself or push itself away.

Right now I only have a lift that moves the cargo accordingly with credible friction and also reacts to the velocity of the forklift but if I hit the forks against walls or other static colliders, the forks just go through and the forklift doesn't react at all ( I'm just syncing the forks rigidbody with the movement of the lift using `FixedUpdate`).

I have tried using different approaches and some physics libraries compatible with Unity ( Newton Dynamics, Bullet ) but yet, none have succeeded.

## Attempted solutions

### First approach

Using kinematic rigidbodies for all the sections of the lift

#### Details

I created a simple script to move two rigidbodies like how a piston would behave, the code would look something like this:

```
public class Piston : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody LinkedRigidbody;

    public Vector3 MovementDirection = Vector3.up;

    public float MaxPushDistance = 1;

    public float Distance
    {
        get
        {
            return _distance;
        }
        set
        {
            _distance = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, MaxPushDistance);
        }
    }

    private float _distance = 0;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (LinkedRigidbody == null) return;

        LinkedRigidbody.position = transform.TransformPoint(this.transform.localPosition + (MovementDirection * Distance));
    }

}
```

#### Issues

The script had friction issues, the objects on the forks didn't behave correctly and the movement of the forks was jerky when tested against static objects and heavy dynamic objects

### Second approach

Using two layers for collision and two sets of colliders for the forks

#### Details

I set up different layers for the collision Forklift/Environment and Forklift/Cargo, this made the forklift correctly react to crashes against walls and it would react correctly when pushing its forks against static objects.
The cargo also responded to the movement of the forks and had some friction from the movement of the forklift.

#### Issues

The force of the cargo against the forks was unstable, sometimes the force was exponential or sometimes there was none, also, the setup was too complex and not too maintainable.

Also, to try and stabilize the unstable friction/force of the setup, I had to make a script that locked the cargo to the forks so the velocity of the forks was inherited to the cargo and simulate friction, yet this script was not really calculating any friction and sometimes the cargo was not released on time and the forks were pulling the cargo while not fully in contact ( Eg. Just the tip of the forks were touching the cargo and yet the cargo fully moved with the forks )

### Third approach

Use a joint and move it and/or change its properties to behave like a piston

#### Details

The setup was:

A base rigidbody attached to the root of the forklift and having the forks as a platform they would push using the spring force of the joint ( Spring Joint ).

#### Issues

Moving the joint and changing its properties resulted in an unstable movement using realistic weights for the cargo, also, the simulation was too unstable when hitting static colliders ( Environment )

## Other approaches

I have also tried using some physics setups ( But not integrating them with the forklift model ), most of them were not good enough to even try and make a full setup with the forklift

### Hinge Joints

I made several setups trying to make two or more hinge joints move on a single axis or simulate the movement on a single axis ( Sync the rotation of the joints so they would keep the platform on a single axis )

Tried changing friction type, solver iterations, velocity iterations, and many more physics settings, types of joints, joint settings, scripts, etc.

All of them had one or more of the following issues:

- Objects bouncing in the platform even with highest physics quality settings
- Aggressive force reactions ( Heavy objects falling on the platform or just standing on top )
- The inability of handling correctly through scripts ( User control )
- Lack of friction

### Newton Dynamics

The [Newton Dynamics](http://newtondynamics.com/forum/newton.php) library was promising but the support for Unity has some [issues](https://github.com/svenberra/NewtonUnityPlugin/commit/6b6de59eeee44856306311b65d8fe564529510a2) and sadly I don't have enough time to cooperate with the maintainer and test if it's a solution, we don't have too many human resources right now to even try

### Bullet

I can't even recall why that didn't work, but well, if someone tells me that it is the solution, I'll definitely try again

## Current approach

Right now the setup is just:

The complete model of the forklift procedurally animated ( lift ), and a "sync" script that moves a kinematic rigidbody each physics step ( `FixedUpdate` ):

```
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// <para>Collider syncer</para>
/// <para>Allows to sync an object with this transform in the physics loop</para>
/// </summary>
public class CollisionSyncer : MonoBehaviour
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Collision prefab to instantiate
    /// </summary>
    [Tooltip("Prefab de colisión a cargar")]
    public GameObject CollisionPrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// Instanced collision rigidbody
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject InstantiatedCollisionObject { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instanced collision rigidbody
    /// </summary>
    private Rigidbody m_collisionRigidbody;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize collision object
    /// </summary>
    private void Awake()
    {
        InstantiatedCollisionObject = Instantiate(CollisionPrefab);
        m_collisionRigidbody = InstantiatedCollisionObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if (m_collisionRigidbody == null) {
            Debug.LogWarning($"El objeto de colisión para {this.name} no tiene un Rigidbody a sincronizar");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize position
    /// </summary>
    private void Start()
    {
        m_collisionRigidbody.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        m_collisionRigidbody.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update collider position in physics loop
    /// </summary>
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (m_collisionRigidbody != null) {
            m_collisionRigidbody.MovePosition(this.transform.position);
            m_collisionRigidbody.MoveRotation(this.transform.rotation);
        }
    }

}
```

Using this method, the rigidbody syncs perfectly but as I said at the start of this post if the forks collide against a wall, the forks will just go through and ignore the collision ( Until the forklift collider hits directly ), so it's not perfect, but it's much more stable than using the other approaches for handling the cargo

## Possible solutions

### PhysX 4.0

The first time I saw the [PhysX 4.0 announcement video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1rotbzekf0) it seemed like a solution for all the issues I have right now, for example, the stability with the articulated joints is enough to create a simple physics model ( As seen with the lift in the video ), it pretty much seems like the solution to this dilemma, but, Unity has yet to support PhysX 4.0 and the experimental builds do not have articulations or build support, also, I haven't seen any way of integrating PhysX 4.0 with a custom DLL or something like that, and that would require too much work to integrate I think

### Custom physics scripts

I also thought of creating a friction script and use common rigidbody sync for the forklift, but I am no physics expert and really don't have a clue on how to do something like that

Another option would be to create some sort of custom joint or physics component, but as far as I have seen, unless I am able of understanding the full PhysX source code, it is a no-no

Comment: We can help with specific issues, but we can't just give you a blanket answer to such a broad question. Forumlate the particular issues you had. Why didn't the other solutions work? What went wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using ConfigurableJoints for this purpose?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, I have, but sadly they are somewhat difficult for me and yet while testing I haven't found a configuration that does what I need them to do

Comment: @Almo  Sorry, I thought that maybe some new perspective on the issue or something that I could have completely disregarded could be the solution, still, I have added some more details about what I have investigated and possible solutions I have seen

Comment: @LeopoldoJuárez hey, no problem. Keeping to concise answerable questions keeps the site's Q&A useful for future users who may have the same problem! :)

Comment: Welcome to the world of tuning! We make such things as forklifts but we don't use Unity, nor PhysX as our engine. We have one body per part, all of them attached with joints. All dynamic bodies that we use as loads have the same mass for easier tuning. We also have specific collision joint properties for each of the probable collisions combinations. It takes a lot of time to get everything right.